# PHP MySQL - Update with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

Short explain what I want to do.. when I click my button "calc1" my inputs number(quantity1) should be reduced by the inputs number I type in (amount1) Like " Result = quantity1 - amount1 ". In the input "quantity1" is already a value because I loaded it from my database into the input but the calculation doesn't work. I hope you understand me a bit..I better show my code now..

Calculation code:

```
<?php
 include_once('connect.php');

 if($_POST['calc1']){
 $_POST['quantity1'] = $_POST['quantity1'] - $_POST['amount1'];

 $sql = "UPDATE
        tbl_auction
      SET
        quantity1      = $_POST['quantity1']
      WHERE
        id = :user_id";

 $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $query ->execute(array('quantity1' => $_POST['quantity1'] ));
 } else{
 echo 'ups, error!';
 }
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="move_amount">
  <input type="text" class="amount" name="amount1">
</div>

<div id="move_quantity">
<input type="text" class="tend_quantity" name="quantity1" value=" <?=$value_quantity1 ?>"  > 
</div>

<div id="move_btn">
  <input class="btn_sel" name="calc1" type="submit" name="submitted" value="Bidding">
</div>
```

Here is the part from my database that I want to update

```
id  AUTO_INCREMENT
quantity1   int(11)
```

I appreciate every help!

EDIT: My user_id declaration:

```
if ($result[0]["password"] !==    md5($_POST['password'].'D6tp'.$_POST['email'])) {
 header('Location: /PHP/index.php?page=login');
} else {
   $_SESSION['loged_in'] = true;
   $_SESSION['user_id']  = $result[0]["id"]; 
   header('Location: /PHP');
```

};

EDIT: The Problem is solved! For those who want to know what the issue was: So first @arkascha had some good corrections you can see her post... and the secound issue was because in my inputs value was a string written and that's why the calculation did not work too. Thanks to @arkascha!

Comment: have you tried putting: `$_POST['quantity1'` and `$_POST['amount1']` in a variable?

Comment: @BRoebie Putting them in variables or using them as they are, has no difference.

Comment: @VermaJr. really how would you do it then. Because I am quiet new to PHP. So I what to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @BRoebie Try doing this: Create a new PHP page with this code: `<?php $_GET['q'] = $_GET['q'] - $_GET['a']; echo $_GET['q']; ?>` Suppose, the name of the file is: test.php. Then, open localhost/test.php?q=3&a=1. You'll see '2' on that page. Check this: http://wtf.usa.cc/sof2.php?q=3&a=1

Comment: A side note: the old `md5()` hashing algorithm is very insecure to store passwords. It can be easily cracked once the hashes got stolen. You should port to a better implementation. This is the best php based implementation I found so far, though it needs some polishing: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm and this is a readworthy introduction: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Thank you verry much @arkascha. I'll work on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some small issues here:

1. you should not specify `$_POST['quantity1']` directly in the query, since you want to hand it over as a parameter. So instead put in a placeholder: `:quantity1`.
2. you already have a placeholder for the `id` column, great! But you forgot to supply a value for that in your call to execute()!
3. you should not overwrite `$_POST['quantity1']`, though that certainly is possible from a technical point of view. The superglobal `$_POST` should be considered as a read-only source of data, use a local variable instead. That makes the code easier to follow.

So try this instead:

```
<?php 
include_once('connect.php');

if($_POST['calc1']) {
    $quantity1 = $_POST['quantity1'] - $_POST['amount1'];

    $sql = 'UPDATE tbl_auction SET quantity1 = :quantity1 WHERE id = :user_id';

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query ->execute(array(
        'user_id' => $some_user_id, // this has to be some user id
        'quantity1' => $quantity1
    ));
} else{
    echo 'ups, error!';
}
```

You obviously still have to adapt a little here, but the general issues should be addressed, I hope.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your fast answer! You're absolute right. I tried it and the problem is solved. But he doesn't update now. When I click my button now, he does execute it, but the number in quantity1 is exact the same

Comment: @Taylor OK, then two details have to be checked: 1. what is the value of `$some_user_id`? Have you _really_ chose a correct one? Where does it come from? If that is wrong, then obviously no update will occur. 2. are you really sure the computation works? You should check if `$_POST['amount1']` _really_ contains when you expect.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check that and reply in a few minutes back

Comment: @Taylor Actually when looking at that I get the impression that the name `user_id` is suspicious. Looks a bit like copy&paste without giving it any though. What is that `id` column? Probably _not_ some `user_id` I would guess, but an `id` of a record in some product table or similar. So where does that `id` come from which identifies your row you want to update?

Comment: So I will edit after that comment my post. The user_id is a Session which will be set when the user login. So the user_id is the current logged in user......@you can see the user_id declaration now in my first post

Comment: @Taylor That sounds a bit funny to me if I consider the table name... To me this reads as if something is missing in the query, something to further identify the specific row that should be updated. But then again I don't know your table layout. I suggest you post that along in your question...

Comment: No. This table is just for my "auction" the user id is in a other "table" tbl_user.

Comment: @Taylor I suspected that. Then how do you expect your statement to work, if you hand in a "user id" that does not exist in that table?

Comment: because I declared it in a Session variable and in my " connect.php" I start the session with "session_start()" so I should've access to that or?

Comment: @Taylor You confuse a few things here. Certainly you have access to your session variables. But look at your sql statement! In there you have to identify _which_ row to update, right? That happens by means of the `WHERE` clause. In there you reference an `id` column inside table `tbl_auction` which is fine. But you have to feed the correct values for that `id`, not the `user_id` value from your session if I am not completely mistaken. But again: without your table definitions this is unclear.

Comment: Oh wait...of course lol. I'll try something. Thanks for your really convincing amazing answer

Comment: Haha! You was totally right. I just deleted the WHERE to see what happens. And see there. It does work. Of course... I just have to see why the result is -100 when I want to reduce the 1000 with 100 lawl